# Android retrofit OAuth twitch api i am getting different access token each second

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I made a GET request

```
@GET("/oauth2/authorize?client_id=id&scope=scope&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token")
fun getContent():Call<ResponseBody>
```

and i get a access token, but, when i open webview, each second i'm getting new access token

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id=id&scope=scope&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token"))
startActivity(intent)
```

after that code i get this webview, but this access token which i marked a red circle is changing each second, and in the logcat a am getting a lot of tokens, and when i press back button nothing happens,
webview updating all the time.
How to get access token one time and after it close the webview?

[image]

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="localhost"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Any reason for getting the access token using REST? Why not using the Auth0 SDK?

Comment: com.auth0.android.authentication.AuthenticationException: An error occurred when trying to authenticate with the server.

Comment: Activity com.auth0.android.provider.AuthenticationActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.auth0.android.provider.CustomTabsController@abd8e83 that was originally bound here

Comment: how to solve this?